# Jetty make doPost asyncronously

Tags: java, jetty

We have a long-working `doPost` method, which blocks Jetty thread

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // ...
    // long prepare answer (which depends on external sources wait)
    // here must be something like yield

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(answer);
}
```

Is there a way to do the long prepare asynchronously and yield to another Jetty tasks there while it will not be completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Jetty's Continuation API.  Basically a continuation is a mechanism where you start a potentially long running operation in an asynchronous manner and then you free up the Jetty thread that is handling the current request.  When your asynchronous operation completes you use a continuation to resume the processing of the request and at that point you can finish the response.  See [Continuation](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/8.1.17.v20150415/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/continuation/Continuation.html)

Comment: Continuations is deprecated in Jetty 9+ in favor of the Servlet 3.1 built-in AsyncContext feature.  In fact the [default implementation of Continuations in Jetty 9](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.6.v20151106/jetty-continuation/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/continuation/Servlet3Continuation.java) is just a thin layer over the Servlet 3 AsyncContext.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use 2 features of the Servlet spec.

1. [`AsyncContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html) - The Asynchronous Processing feature of the Servlet spec - allowing you to suspend the active processing until such time you actually have some content to generate back on the response. (this is an over-simplification, but you get the gist)
2. [`HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream().setWriteListener(WriteListener)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html#setWriteListener-javax.servlet.WriteListener-) - The Asynchronous I/O feature of the Servlet spec - for asynchronously generating / writing a response back to the client.  (this is also a simplification, but [be aware of the gotchas when working with this](https://youtu.be/j1VjAHTxCBo))